# Adding a JLabel to a Frame For a Game Character

Tags: java, jframe, jlabel

I am trying to add a JLabel in my main method with the image of a chicken. When I add the label to the frame, nothing shows up. I also need to have the chicken placed on the frame with coordinates. This is my code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MediaTracker;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class TEST extends JFrame {
  /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

TEST(){
    add(new ContentPanel());
    setSize(1440, 500);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TEST jrframe = new TEST();
    jrframe.setVisible(true);
    JLabel chicken = new JLabel(" ");
    ImageIcon chick = new ImageIcon("chicken.gif");
    chicken.setIcon(chick);
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.add(chicken);
    jrframe.add(p1);
    p1.setLocation(0, 0);
  }
}

class ContentPanel extends JPanel{
  Image bgimage = null;

  ContentPanel() {
    MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(this);
    bgimage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("level0.gif");
    mt.addImage(bgimage, 0);
    try {
      mt.waitForAll();
    } catch (InterruptedException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    int imwidth = bgimage.getWidth(null);
    int imheight = bgimage.getHeight(null);
    g.drawImage(bgimage, 1, 1, null);
  }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend constructing your UI on the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), and follow [java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding Components to an already visible Frame. When doing so, you need to notify the LayoutManager this is occurring, or better yet move the call `setVisible(true)` after adding the Components.

Comment: When I try to change the jrframe.setVisible(true); after the jrframe.add(p1);, it will only show the image in that panel.

Comment: This is due to the LayoutManager - the default LayoutManager of the content pane is BorderLayout, which cannot have two Components in its `CENTER` location. For demonstration, in the first line of the TEST constructor, change the layout by calling `getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout())`  See [A Visual Guide To LayoutManagers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for further information.